Flutter Screenshot Vertical Horizontal Pdf A4 Size Problem
I Am working on a reporting app that produces PDF files in a4 format. my code working well but while it has large data it's not working properly.
I Use RepaintBoundary | screenshot | Pdf | 

My Code As Follows: -
body: Screenshot(
        controller: _screenshotController,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: RepaintBoundary(
              key: _screenshotKey,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                width: 2100.0, // Set a fixed width or use a sized container
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>

Create Screenshot:-
final boundary = _screenshotKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()
        as RenderRepaintBoundary;
    boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 1.0).then((image) async {
      ByteData? byteData =
          await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
      Uint8List uint8List = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
      switch (choice) {
        case 'Pdf':
          getPdf(uint8List);
          break;
        case 'ScreenShoot':
          Uint8List imageBytes = uint8List;
          final output = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
          final file = File('${output?.path}/example.png');
          await file.writeAsBytes(imageBytes);
          // Open the generated PDF file
          OpenFile.open(file.path);
      }
    });

GetPdf Code:-
Future<void> getPdf(Uint8List screenShot) async {
  final pdf = pw.Document();

  final img.Image? longScreenshot = img.decodeImage(screenShot);

  if (longScreenshot == null) {
    throw Exception('Could not decode image');
  }

  final double a4Height = 3540; // in pixels

  final int pageCount = (longScreenshot.height / a4Height).ceil();

  //Add screenshot sections to separate pages
  for (int page = 0; page < pageCount; page++) {
    int start = (page * a4Height).toInt();
    int end = ((page + 1) * a4Height).toInt();

    if (end > longScreenshot.height) {
      end = longScreenshot.height;
    }

    final img.Image section = img.copyCrop(
      longScreenshot,
      x: 0,
      y: start,
      width: longScreenshot.width,
      height: end - start,
    );

    Uint8List pngBytes = img.encodePng(section);

    pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Expanded(
          child: pw.Image(pw.MemoryImage(pngBytes)),
        );
      },
    ));
  }

  final output = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  final file = File('${output?.path}/example.pdf');
  await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
  // Open the generated PDF file
  OpenFile.open(file.path);
}

In this If Small Data within 5 Pages that's works well while using
pixelRatio: 3.0

but when large data first
final int pageCount = (longScreenshot.height / a4Height).ceil();

not working properly pagecount.
Help me With It.
Thanks In Advance.
